# Serializing an object then sending to a server, laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

I am serializing a form and successfully get the object I want to send, but when the POST request is made the browser only passes in the `playerName` attribute, only that attribute, even if I change the input name and pass another attribute in the place of `playerName` it won't pass, unless it is the `playerName` attr.

Here is my backbone.js javascript code to save my form as an object.

```
savePlayer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var playerDetails = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();

    console.log(playerDetails); // this returns perfectly with all attributes

    // I tried this with a model, saving it
    var player = new App.Models.Player();
    player.save(playerDetails);

    // and with a collection creating it
    var playersCollection = new App.Collections.PlayersCollection();
    playersCollection.create(playerDetails);

    return false;
}
```

For now I am trying to save two attributes `playerName` and `teamID`, so the form serializes appropriately like this `{playerName: 'mike', teamID: '2'}` when save/create is called there is a POST method and the controller that handles that is below.

```
// First attempt
public function store()
{
    return Player::create(array( 
        'playerName' => Input::get('playerName'),  
        'teamID' => Input::get('teamID')       
    ));
}

//Second try
public function store()
{
    // I used this
    $input = Input::json();
    // And this (not same time lol)
    $input = Input::all();

    return Player::create(array( 
        'playerName' => $input->playerName, 
        'teamID' => $input->teamID       
    ));

}
```

In the POST response it seems that the attributes do pass into the `Post` tab, but in the `Response` and `JSON` they don't show up only the `playerName` attr.

**Post**

```
//source
{"playerName":"Joesph","teamID":"1"} // Good
```

but in the

**Response**

```
//It gets an id for the table, a smart feature from backbone.js 
{"playerName":"Joesph","id":23} // Missing "teamID":"1"?
```

Just for extra measure here is my form.

New Player

```
  <label>First & Last Name</label>
  <input name="playerName" type="text" value="">
  <hr />
  // Here I tried dynamic like below and static, just passing in a number like "2"
  <input type="hidden" name="teamID" value="<%= team.teamID %>" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
```

Also with the form above in the place of `playerName` I tried using `teamID`, and other attributes on the model, nothing works but that attr?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this got me before as it doesn't make much sense to me, but when sending data to the server, I need to use the `$fillable` variable. I think I need to read more about it.

```
// I needed to add it to this array
protected $fillable = array('playerID', 'playerName', 'teamID');
```

So this code resides inside my models on the class name which is `Player`, here is the full code for that model.

```
class Player extends Eloquent {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('playerID', 'playerName', 'teamID');
}
```

Now the code in my original post works, whew hate little frustrating bumps like this one. Hope I didn't waste any ones time, and I hope this could help someone using backbone.js and laravel!